# Riddle - Can you guess what am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> Year after year, I disrespect time,
> Don't keep looking and waste your prime,
> A lot happens underneath,
> You just have to look beneath.
>
> Remember Rome wasn't built in a day,
> I don't care if you think I lost.
> Oh! I must tell you - I'm not a good host.
>
> Don't lose tenacity and believe in my capacity.
> I like people who wait because it's a rare trait.
>
> I'm not abstract like success, fame, hope and fear,
> Help me cope, don't subtract or distract me my dear.

Hints (3 days after the question):-

> I'm used to make a variety of goods.
>  I rest in small bowls many a times.

Comment: Maybe it's the fan in me speaking, but this so accurately describes Roger Federer!

Comment: @Sid This is what I like about this community. You guys come up with so many answers when I least expect them :)

Comment: Is it related to computers / electronics..? (I keep getting sidetracked by the "capacity" line)

Comment: @whrrgarbl It isn't related to electronics :)

Comment: i want to say 'calendar or time table' but again not able to fit all clues

Comment: @WeShall Nope. Should I edit the question and drop more hints given that it's been quite some time?

Comment: You Probably need to provide more hints....

Comment: @Sid Done. Added a hint.

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal is it an eatable thing :p ?

Comment: @Techidiot I've already given out too many hints. Can't give out anything else. I've already told it's nothing related to computers and I also added a few more hints today :)

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal, by any chance is it 'crystal'... fits a few clues but others I might have to dig deeper.

Comment: @WeShall Nope it ain't crystal.

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal Is it petrol?

Comment: @Sumit I'm afraid not.

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal  I guess it is a Bamboo Tree

Comment: @Sumit Please answer the question so that I can accept it. And do you mind if I make some edits to your answer so that I can explain the hints in detail?

Comment: Sounds like it's clay but I can't figure out what clay would have to do with the first stanza

Comment: @somebody Seems like a reasonable answer. Try putting it up as an answer and we all can think of something to fit the first stanza as well.

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal I have answered the question now, please make edits at your will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is

> Chinese Bamboo

Year after year, I disrespect time Don't keep looking and waste your prime,

> Chinese Bamboo doesn't grow at all for years. You can't see the tiniest shoot.

A lot happens underneath, You just have to look beneath.

> Nothing happens on top but it is developing solid roots beneath the layer of soil.

Remember Rome wasn't built in a day, I don't care if you think I lost.

> After a given number of years of zero growth, it shoots up to great heights in just weeks.

Oh! I must tell you - I'm not a good host.

> It is not like other trees which give lot of shadow, nor birds/animals can stay on it so easily like other trees.

Don't lose tenacity and believe in my capacity. I like people who wait because it's a rare trait.

> The person who planted it shouldn't lose hope just because it takes time. He should believe in the capacity.

I'm not abstract like success, fame, hope and fear, Help me cope, don't subtract or distract me my dear.

> Let the tree grow for the time it needs. Subtract refers to the act of cutting it. Distract refers to anything else that can harm the tree.

Comment: Can I edit it to include some useful details? Will edit it to explain hints and some minor changes here and there :)

Comment: Yes, you can definitely edit it :)

Comment: Done. Have edited quite a bit. Sorry for that.

Comment: It would be great it you could explain why you chose this answer :)

Comment: Actually the answer by @geisterfurz007 helped me. That was good answer but only thing missing was the connection with the hint "I rest in small bowls many a times". Then suddenly it clicked me that we keep those bamboo trees in the small bowls for good luck in homes/offices. As you given the comment for his answer to be best one, I guessed it is very near to the correct answer.

Comment: Yupeeh I have been helpul ;) That bothered me as well to not get any connection to the hints given. Another thing is that in German this is just reffered to as bamboo (without tree) so beeing close with tree confused me, but I do not think I would have come to bamboo ever...

Answer (score 5):

> If it's wrong, apologies in advance for the nerdiness. My guess is: a derivative.

Year after year, I disrespect time,

> since it'd be dx/dt

Don't keep looking and waste your prime,

> x' is analogous to dx/dt

A lot happens underneath,
You just have to look beneath.

> the integral (area under the curve)

Remember Rome wasn't built in a day,
I don't care if you think I lost.
Oh! I must tell you - I'm not a good host.

> a negative value of dx/dt doesn't mean that it can't become positive later on at another point

Don't lose tenacity and believe in my capacity.
I like people who wait because it's a rare trait.

> the formula for heat capacity is sometimes integrated

I'm not abstract like success, fame, hope and fear,
Help me cope, don't subtract or distract me my dear.

> here my reasoning gets sloppier... but it makes little sense to subtract dx/dt

Comment: Good one not the answer though. You needn't feel sorry, anything that goes with most of the hints is acceptable. That's what most people do. +1 :)

Answer (score 4):

First guess

Are you?

> A Damaged/Non working TV Remote Control

Year after year, I disrespect time,
Don't keep looking and waste your prime,
A lot happens underneath,
You just have to look beneath.

> A non working remote control consumes a lot of time. Just looking at
> it won't fix it. Its an electrical device and hence a lot happens
> inside it. Just look beneath, remove and replace the batteries.

Remember Rome wasn't built in a day,
I don't care if you think I lost.

> It takes time for the remote to get working.

Oh! I must tell you - I'm not a good host.

> May be because its made of plastic and is not a good conductor of electricity.

Don't lose tenacity and believe in my capacity.
I like people who wait because it's a rare trait.

> Don't lose the grip and hold it good else it will be spoiled even more.
> Most of us just throw or bang it. There are some who have the
> patience.

Comment: Nice answer. Maybe you can add this to it. Distraction stands for blocking it's view so that it cannot communicate with you know what. +1 for the creativity :)

Comment: @Techidiot is living his name ;) Interesting answer. I think I will never be as creative as the most puzzlers here ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
Are you...
```

> **Winter**

```
Year after year, I disrespect time,
Don't keep looking and waste your prime,
```

> With short days and long nights, winter makes it feel like time has slowed down. Don't waste time and make most of the day.

```
A lot happens underneath,
You just have to look beneath.
```

> There is a lot you can do indoors, you just need to look for it.

```
Remember Rome wasn't built in a day,
```

> This along with 3rd stanza, emphasis on being patient

```
I don't care if you think I lost.
Oh! I must tell you - I'm not a good host.
```

> Winter is not a good host and even when we think winter is over, it does not care as it is bound to return the next year

```
Don't lose tenacity and believe in my capacity.
I like people who wait because it's a rare trait.
```

> Don't give up, toil through the colder months and wait patiently for the spring

```
I'm not abstract like success, fame, hope and fear,
Help me cope, don't subtract or distract me my dear.
```

> Global warming is real and diminishing winter is asking for our help to survive.

Comment: A good attempt but not the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Shot in the dark, are you...

> A leap year and/or February 29th ? (which may have been the answer to another riddle)

---

Year after year, I disrespect time,

> I'd say the non leap years disrespect time and the leap years come along to put things back in order, but in a sense they're all disrespecting time by not sharing it evenly.

Don't keep looking and waste your prime,

> 29 is a prime number

A lot happens underneath,
You just have to look beneath.

> This line makes me think I'm wrong

Remember Rome wasn't built in a day,

> Feb 29 is a day. Ironically, Rome *was* built on it.

I don't care if you think I lost.

> Feb 29 gets lost in the calendar and only shows up every 4 years

Oh! I must tell you - I'm not a good host.

> It's a terrible host. It's always 3 years late

Don't lose tenacity and believe in my capacity.
I like people who wait because it's a rare trait.

> Wait 3 more years than you normally have to and it will come around again

I'm not abstract like success, fame, hope and fear,
Help me cope, don't subtract or distract me my dear.

> This line also makes me think I'm wrong

Comment: Like your view of the answer not giving up hope. Not the right answer though. Upvote for such an unexpected answer that meets the criteria :)

Answer (score 2):

Is it -

> SALT

Year after year, I disrespect time,
Don't keep looking and waste your prime,

> It's been one of the un ending resource for years now.

A lot happens underneath,
You just have to look beneath.

> Refers to Salt Mines.

Remember Rome wasn't built in a day,
I don't care if you think I lost.

> Earliest known salt works in the world were made near the village of Lunca in Romania. May be relevant.

Oh! I must tell you - I'm not a good host.

> Self explanatory. Tastes bad.

Don't lose tenacity and believe in my capacity.
I like people who wait because it's a rare trait.

> Its smooth and can flow away through hands. It has a lot of good tendencies.

Comment: Not the answer. +1 for an answer that meets quite a few conditions :)

Answer (score 2):

**Partial Answer**

Are you:

> Water?

Year after year, I disrespect time

> Refers to erosion, which happens over many years.

Don't keep looking and waste your prime

> A reference Narcissus in Greek mythology, who looked at his handsome reflection in water for so long that he died.

A lot happens underneath, you just have to look beneath.

> Even if water is calm on the surface, it can be turbulent underneath due to currents.

Remember Rome wasn't built in a day, I don't care if you think I lost.

> Rome is built on the river Tiber, which was prone to flooding before Rome eventually started building defences in 1876. In this battle, water has lost!

Oh! I must tell you - I'm not a good host.

> As a human, you'll drown if you stay underwater for too long unaided.

Don't lose tenacity...

> Humans need to drink water to survive.

...believe in my capacity.

> Approximately 71% of the Earth is covered in water. It could hold a lot of stuff.

Still not sure about these, though...

- I like people who wait because it's a rare trait.
- Help me cope, don't subtract or distract me my dear.

Comment: +1 liked it except the last two points. _I like people who wait because it's a rare trait_ this might be stating that people can wait for rains to shower the water. _dont subtract/distract me_ this might be don't waste me.

Comment: @Techidiot Good point. -Daniel I think you've based your answer on the small bowl :) +1 for the good answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about

> **Zero**

Year after year, I disrespect time,
Don't keep looking and waste your prime,

> O is a weird number, it isn't prime and it can't really be classified into any mathematical number group. It disrespects time because nothing can't be timed

A lot happens underneath,
You just have to look beneath.

> The negative numbers go on infinitely, as do the positive, you just have to look below zero

Remember Rome wasn't built in a day,
I don't care if you think I lost.
Oh! I must tell you - I'm not a good host.

> Don't know about Rome but generally if you get zero in a game, (football etc.) you probably lost

Don't lose tenacity and believe in my capacity.
I like people who wait because it's a rare trait.

> Zero has no capacity, it is nothing.

I'm not abstract like success, fame, hope and fear,
Help me cope, don't subtract or distract me my dear.

> It's not abstract and if you subtract it from a number nothing happens so that is pointless

Comment: +1 for a nice answer. Added some more hints, perhaps you can retry :)

Comment: 0 is an even number, and "even" is a class of numbers.

Comment: @GarrisonPendergrass I mean apart from even an odd

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> a seed?

```
Year after year, I disrespect time
```

> a seed grows into a plant which produces seeds and the cycle repeats

```
Don't keep looking and waste your prime,
A lot happens underneath,
You just have to look beneath.
```

> a seed is planted in earth; you don't see anything, all the magic happens beneath the surface

```
Remember Rome wasn't built in a day,
I don't care if you think I lost.
```

> it takes a while for the plant to reach surface and show itself, even if you think that nothing will happen, it was a bad seed

```
Oh! I must tell you - I'm not a good host.
```

> the plant doesn't want to stay in the seed, it breaks free

```
Don't lose tenacity and believe in my capacity.
I like people who wait because it's a rare trait.
```

> again, be patient and believe that a plant will emerge at the surface

```
I'm not abstract like success, fame, hope and fear,
Help me cope, don't subtract or distract me my dear.
```

> give me time, water me and let me grow

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.+1 This is the best answer so far. If nobody gets it right, you will get the bounty :)

Answer (score 1):

First time, so lets give it a shot:

Are you

> A tree? This is most likely based on [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/44871/30279)

Year after year, I disrespect time,
Don't keep looking and waste your prime,

> Every year it gains a ring -> trophy / disrespect
>  Looking into them means cutting them down and wasting one of our prime ressources

A lot happens underneath,
You just have to look beneath.

> Same thing as c4n: Gaining ressources of the tree and exchange of nutrients happens at the roots

Remember Rome wasn't built in a day,
I don't care if you think I lost.

> For example an apple tree takes a long time until he finally produces apples.

Oh! I must tell you - I'm not a good host.

> You have to get the fruit and will not get it served

Don't lose tenacity and believe in my capacity.
I like people who wait because it's a rare trait.

> Waiting for the trees to grow until they will grow fruit will take a long time

I'm not abstract like success, fame, hope and fear,
Help me cope, don't subtract or distract me my dear.

> Help to get the tree to grow and get rid of possibly harmful animals

Maybe does not quite fit the hint though, but has been fun to think through.
Again: This is most likely based on c4n's answer :)

Comment: Very close to the answer. I'm afraid that Sumit got to the exact answer a few minutes ago. +1 for coming **so** close. If it's possible to split a bounty, I'll give a portion of it to you :)

Comment: Sorry. It's not possible to split a bounty. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users

Comment: Darn... How unsatisfying ^^ Knowing you are so close and not having the answer... I am curious to see what was expected :) Not problem with the bounty :) Most of it has been copied/refined by c4n's answer anyways :D

Comment: Read the comments just below the question. The answer's there. I've asked him to write an answer.

Comment: THAT CLOSE?! O-O Damn it ^^ But how would you get to SPOILER ? I am curious to see his answer...

Comment: If his explanation doesn't match, I'll edit and improve it :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it -

> Plastic

Year after year, I disrespect time
Don't keep looking and waste your prime,

> Plastics are non-biodegradable

A lot happens underneath,
You just have to look beneath.

> A lot of chains of polymers are formed inside it. You just need to look beneath a microscope.

Remember Rome wasn't built in a day,
I don't care if you think I lost.

> It takes time to form the plastic from polymers, petroleum and natural gas.

Oh! I must tell you - I'm not a good host.

> Its not a good conductor of electricity.

Don't lose tenacity and believe in my capacity.
I like people who wait because it's a rare trait.

> Molten plastic may slip off hands but you have to wait for it to be stronger. The process is called Thermoforming.

I'm not abstract like success, fame, hope and fear,
Help me cope, don't subtract or distract me my dear.

> Don't throw plastic.

I'm used to make a variety of goods.

> Self explanatory

I rest in small bowls many a times

> Plastic bowls

Comment: Nope. It isn't the answer.